# Server Install With Deep Partitions

Tags: partitioning

I've been playing around with a SIEM and their security recommendations suggest the following directories be created as separate partitions (with additional security added).

```
/dev/shm
/home
/tmp
/var
/var/log
/var/log/audit
/var/tmp
```

During the Ubuntu server install, it's easy to create the first level partitions.  But, it errors if I attempt to go two or three directories deep.  During the installation I also tried creating the first level partition, then the second level, and that errors too. Likely because the second level can't be created until the first level has been created.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The partitioner in the installer is a convenience for many users. Its use is not required.

Advanced users with complex needs should manually partition (for example, by using the Live environment) before launching the installer.

If a community member wants to patch the installer partitioner to make more complex mount points possible, go right ahead and contribute that improvement to Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks.  I found the "live" environment during initial boot.  Which tool do I use to create and mount partitions?  The ones I'm used to don't seem to be there.

Comment: Install the tool you want. The Live environment can use apt and snap.

Comment: I don't have apt or snap at my Grub command line.

Comment: Of course not. The Grub command-line is part of booting. It's not part of a running Live environment.

Comment: My apologies for my ignorance, are you saying that I need to build my Ubuntu Server instance from the initial wizard, then go back and build, and migrate, the additional partitions?